# Encrypt a file inside an ODS archive

Tags: java, encryption, aes, libreoffice, ods

I'm trying to reproduce the LibreOffice encryption of a file inside an ODS (open document spreadsheet) archive. See http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part3.html#__RefHeading__752811_826425813 for technical information.

The best summary I found is in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification#Encryption):

> When OpenDocument file is password protected the file structure of the bundle remains the same, but contents of XML files in the package are encrypted using following algorithm:
>
> 1. The file contents are compressed with the DEFLATE algorithm.
> 2. A checksum of a portion of the compressed file is computed (SHA-1 of the file contents, or SHA-1 of the first 1024 bytes of the file, or SHA-256 of the first 1024 bytes of the file) and stored so password correctness can be verified when decrypting.
> 3. A digest (hash) of the user entered password in UTF-8 encoding is created and passed to the package component. ODF versions 1.0 and 1.1 only mandate support for the SHA-1 digest here, while version 1.2 recommends SHA-256.
> 4. This digest is used to produce a derived key by undergoing key stretching with PBKDF2 using HMAC-SHA-1 with a salt of arbitrary length (in ODF 1.2 – it's 16 bytes in ODF 1.1 and below) generated by the random number generator for an arbitrary iteration count (1024 by default in ODF 1.2).
> 5. The random number generator is used to generate a random initialization vector for each file.
> 6. The initialization vector and derived key are used to encrypt the compressed file contents. ODF 1.0 and 1.1 use Blowfish in 8-bit cipher feedback mode, while ODF 1.2 considers it a legacy algorithm and allows Triple DES and AES (with 128, 196 or 256 bits), both in cipher block chaining mode, to be used instead.

My un-encrypted module content (encoding: utf-8, line break: LF) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE script:module PUBLIC "-//OpenOffice.org//DTD OfficeDocument 1.0//EN" "module.dtd">
<script:module xmlns:script="http://openoffice.org/2000/script" script:name="Module1" script:language="StarBasic" script:moduleType="normal">REM  *****  BASIC  *****
REM Hello, world!
</script:module>
```

The encrypted module content produced by LibreOffice and stored in the ODS archive, is (in hexadecimal):

```
[a3, f4, 61, 98, c1, c8, e8, b1, d3, fa, b0, bc, ef, 51, 87, da, 4c, d8, 92, c2, 09, 7f, 12, 19, 47, 44, af, 3b, 32, 9d, 4a, 33, eb, ab, c0, 45, 97, 00, 27, 60, cf, b3, 49, 55, 76, 46, e2, 3c, 35, a0, a7, a9, 8a, af, a3, cd, 3c, f3, 20, 5f, 83, 89, a4, 9c, d9, b5, a6, f5, db, 68, 0a, b4, d0, 15, 3e, 6d, af, c6, 16, 78, 29, 79, 42, cb, 56, e3, b1, cd, c1, a6, a0, 13, 91, 16, e3, 89, a8, c6, d4, 69, e8, ea, 87, e9, 9d, 09, bb, 03, a0, 6e, a0, 29, 37, 85, 9a, 59, fb, 47, 3a, 72, 1d, 85, 25, b0, 92, 37, 55, a4, eb, de, 03, eb, de, e1, b6, f3, f9, 7b, 3a, 09, 2c, ad, 8e, ff, 1e, a2, 79, 63, 12, 04, 93, 67, 3d, 59, 6c, e8, aa, ae, 37, 7e, 66, cf, 99, 54, 63, a5, ea, 31, 78, 44, b1, 54, be, 5a, af, 3f, 0d, bf, b5, ce, 98, c8, 7a, 44, 61, d4, 76, 69, 3b, 01, 6f, 27, ab, 5f, a2, b0, 98, 32, 52, 0c, 9c, 08, 0c, 6a, 0c, 54, e0, 83, dc, d0, ad, 3a, 0f, 0f, 75, 6f, e6, 0d, db, db, 50, a4, 2b, d3, 5f, 43, 7c, 2d, 16, fa, 87, 62, 09, f6, d2, 28, 31, b5, a0, be]
```

And here's the relevant part of the manifest produced by LibreOffice:

```
    <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="Basic/Test/Module1.xml" manifest:media-type="text/xml" manifest:size="332">
     <manifest:encryption-data manifest:checksum-type="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:manifest:1.0#sha256-1k" manifest:checksum="/UdU2OKZn04r0e9O047PaWNqi7LGaHYN9mURmvMCM60=">
      <manifest:algorithm manifest:algorithm-name="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" manifest:initialisation-vector="ZEk8JHG3bHu8kZw0VGOT+g=="/>
      <manifest:key-derivation manifest:key-derivation-name="PBKDF2" manifest:key-size="32" manifest:iteration-count="100000" manifest:salt="jGIagiBnlFdvQctdCkYfRQ=="/>
      <manifest:start-key-generation manifest:start-key-generation-name="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" manifest:key-size="32"/>
     </manifest:encryption-data>
    </manifest:file-entry>
```

The password was `123`.

---

Here's my code:

```
// imports
// needs a dependency on `org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.65`

public class EncryptMacro {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        new EncryptMacro().encryptAsLO();
    }

    public void encryptAsLO() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        // needs a dependency on `org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.65`
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // copy the manifest parameters
        int plainSize = 332;
        byte[] checksum = Base64.decode("/UdU2OKZn04r0e9O047PaWNqi7LGaHYN9mURmvMCM60=");
        byte[] iv = Base64.decode("ZEk8JHG3bHu8kZw0VGOT+g==");
        int iterationCount = 100000;
        byte[] salt = Base64.decode("jGIagiBnlFdvQctdCkYfRQ==");
        int startKeySize = 32;
        int keySize = 32;

        // password
        String password = "123"; // that's for testing purpose!

        String plainText =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE script:module PUBLIC \"-//OpenOffice.org//DTD OfficeDocument 1.0//EN\" \"module.dtd\">\n<script:module xmlns:script=\"http://openoffice.org/2000/script\" script:name=\"Module1\" script:language=\"StarBasic\" script:moduleType=\"normal\">REM  *****  BASIC  *****\nREM Hello, world!\n</script:module>";
        byte[] encrypted =
                new byte[]{-93, -12, 97, -104, -63, -56, -24, -79, -45, -6, -80, -68, -17, 81, -121,
                        -38, 76, -40, -110, -62, 9, 127, 18, 25, 71, 68, -81, 59, 50, -99, 74, 51,
                        -21, -85, -64, 69, -105, 0, 39, 96, -49, -77, 73, 85, 118, 70, -30, 60, 53,
                        -96, -89, -87, -118, -81, -93, -51, 60, -13, 32, 95, -125, -119, -92, -100,
                        -39, -75, -90, -11, -37, 104, 10, -76, -48, 21, 62, 109, -81, -58, 22, 120,
                        41, 121, 66, -53, 86, -29, -79, -51, -63, -90, -96, 19, -111, 22, -29, -119,
                        -88, -58, -44, 105, -24, -22, -121, -23, -99, 9, -69, 3, -96, 110, -96, 41,
                        55, -123, -102, 89, -5, 71, 58, 114, 29, -123, 37, -80, -110, 55, 85, -92,
                        -21, -34, 3, -21, -34, -31, -74, -13, -7, 123, 58, 9, 44, -83, -114, -1, 30,
                        -94, 121, 99, 18, 4, -109, 103, 61, 89, 108, -24, -86, -82, 55, 126, 102,
                        -49, -103, 84, 99, -91, -22, 49, 120, 68, -79, 84, -66, 90, -81, 63, 13,
                        -65, -75, -50, -104, -56, 122, 68, 97, -44, 118, 105, 59, 1, 111, 39, -85,
                        95, -94, -80, -104, 50, 82, 12, -100, 8, 12, 106, 12, 84, -32, -125, -36,
                        -48, -83, 58, 15, 15, 117, 111, -26, 13, -37, -37, 80, -92, 43, -45, 95, 67,
                        124, 45, 22, -6, -121, 98, 9, -10, -46, 40, 49, -75, -96, -66};

        // check the plain text size
        byte[] source = plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        this.check("Plain size", plainSize == source.length);
        // deflate the content (see 1. above)
        byte[] deflated = this.deflate(source);
        // and check the checksum (see 2. above)
        this.check("Deflated hash", Arrays.equals(checksum, this.getSha256_1k(deflated)));

        // hash the password (see 3. above)
        byte[] hashedPassword = this.getSha256_1k(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        char[] chars = new char[hashedPassword.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < hashedPassword.length; i++) {
            chars[i] = (char) hashedPassword[i];
        }
        this.check("Start key size", chars.length == startKeySize);
        // or:
        // char[] chars = password.toCharArray();

        // get the key (see 4. above)
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterationCount, keySize * 8);
        SecretKey s = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(s.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // encrypt the data (see 6. above)
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        // or:
        // Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding"); // W3C padding
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(deflated);

        this.check("Encrypted", Arrays.equals(encrypted, result));
    }

    private byte[] deflate(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[16];  // for testing purpose

        Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true);
        DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(os, deflater);
        int count = is.read(buffer);
        while (count != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
            count = is.read(buffer);
        }
        dos.close();
        return os.toByteArray();
    }

    private byte[] getSha256_1k(byte[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(data, 0, Math.min(data.length, 1024));
        return digest.digest();
    }

    private void check(String text, boolean test) {
        if (test) {
            System.out.println(text + " ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println(text + " NOT ok");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Plain size ok
Deflated hash ok
Start key size ok
Encrypted NOT ok
```

Of course, I would like the generated encrypted data to be identical to the one present in the ODS archive. I tried to change the padding, the key derivation function, to pass the `password` directly to `PBEKeySpec`, triple-checked the password, etc. without success. I also had a look to the source code of LibreOffice (https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/tree/master/oox/source/crypto), but did not manage to find what is wrong in my code. (If that matters, I used LibreOffice Calc Version: 6.0.7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.10 and Java 8.)

My question is: where is my mistake and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

1. According to the specification PBKDF2 is used with HMAC-SHA1 (and not HMAC-SHA256), s. [3.4.2 Encryption Process](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-part3.html#__RefHeading__752815_826425813)
2. The key `s` derived with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` is an instance of `PBKDF2KeyImpl`, which requires a UTF8 string as password (see docs of the [`PBKDF2KeyImpl`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2KeyImpl.java) class). Here, however, the password is a hash, which is generally not compatible with UTF8. A possible solution is to replace `PBEKeySpec` with BouncyCastle's `PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator`, which expects the password as byte array (in `init`). For this solution replace

   ```
   SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
   KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterationCount, keySize * 8);
   SecretKey s = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
   Key key = new SecretKeySpec(s.getEncoded(), "AES");
   ```

   with

   ```
   PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA1Digest()); 
   generator.init(hashedPassword, salt, iterationCount);
   KeyParameter keyParam = (KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(keySize * 8);
   Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyParam.getKey(), "AES");
   ```
3. The padding used is [ISO10126Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#ISO_10126), so `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` must by replaced by `AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding`. The easiest way to verify this is to decrypt the target ciphertext (`encrypted`) without removing the padding (`AES/CBC/NoPadding`). The last block is `06230276DDC67229EB31E830A1D7500F`, which complies with ISO10126Padding. For ISO10126Padding, the last byte specifies the number of padding bytes, which (apart from the last byte) consist of *random* values. So in this case the last 15 bytes are padding bytes.

   ISO10126Padding is also the reason why a comparison of the ciphertext on byte level with

   ```
   this.check("Encrypted", Arrays.equals(encrypted, result));
   ```

   fails. When comparing the ciphertext, the padded block must therefore not be taken into account.

Comment: Great answer!! Now it works... Note that 1. is not true, though: the linked section that talks about SHA-1 is just an illustration ("using the **legacy** algorithms to illustrate each stage"), and the manifest says `manifest:start-key-generation-name="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256"`. 2. works fine and, about 3., even hough I tested the ISO padding, I never thought of the random end of my `result`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jferard - It's true that the linked section talks about _legacy_ algorithms, but the digest used in the context of PBKDF2 _still_ seems to be SHA1, see `new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA1Digest()`). If `SHA1Digest()` is replaced by `SHA256Digest()` here, the _expected_ ciphertext is _not_ generated! This is only possible with `SHA1Digest()`. With 1. exactly this is meant. `manifest:start-key-generation-name="w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256"` defines the digest with which the _initial_ key (`hashPassword`) is derived (indeed SHA256), but _not_ the digest used in the context of PBKDF2.